# Can if statements be broken half way through?

Tags: java, if-statement

I was just wondering if an 'if' statement that is halfway through running will stop running if the conditions it has to meet are no longer met. It is hard to explain with words, here is an example:

```
boolean flag = true;

if(flag){

//Some code execution here (code execution #1)

flag = false;

//Some more code execution here (code execution #2)


}
```

Will the "code execution #2" run in this case? Or will the the rest of the if statement be skipped when flag is set to false?

Comment: Yes, it’ll run; the check only happens once. Did you try it?

Comment: This is what functions are for.

Comment: @mastrgamr ***no you cannot use break.***

Comment: Ooo misread the question, I thought it was meant for a loop.

Comment: Put another nested if there.

Comment: @Qix , Actually you can.

Comment: @DamianNikodem if you use labels, which... don't use labels. Ever, please.

Comment: just changing flag to false won't bail it out

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The entire contents of the if statement will be executed since at the time of the condition check, *flag* equaled true.

Answer (score 0):

Definitely not in the case that you describe, since the condition in the if statemet is evaluated at the time that the if is executed.

if you need a program flow control mechanism to break out of a if statement you can use exceptions (but this is less than ideal for a lot of reasons, )

Alternatively you can use a label and a break statement:

```
    boolean flag = false;
    MYLABEL:
    if (flag) {
        if (true) {
            break MYLABEL;
        }
        System.err.println("I will not execute");
    }
```

Comment: Avoid labels. They are cluttered, non-performant in a lot of languages, prone to bugs and completely human unreadable.

Comment: I appreciate you opinion, though I would like to throw In some facts such as They are also a perfectly valid language construct in Java, c and c++ to name a few and used rather librally in a lot of serious projects ( see Linux kernel, iOS/OS X open source components, etc. ). Alternative options for similar flow control have significant disadvantages.

Comment: Such as? The Linux kernel is incredibly archaic. Do a quick search on readability and labels. You'll find they're generally negatively received. They are valid constructs, but anymore for historical reasons. Compilers optimize the hell out of function calls. The op is obviously new; if they start using labels as a common construct you're setting them up for failure later on.

Comment: Well using a label/break compiles significantly more efficient than a function call because one does not have to push everything onto the stack . And a label also improves readability when having to break out of a loop. If you are calling the Linux kernel archaic can you suggest another similarly complex and mature system level code base ? ( I have worked with a couple of proprietary ones all of which use labels extensively ) it is a lesser know language construct hence why I mentioned it.

Comment: `using a label/break compiles significantly more efficient than a function call` that's speculation. While it's generally probably true, speed is not a specification. **Show me one place anywhere where a labelled if statement is *sensibly* used.** If statements are not loops.